# Does changing the appearance of the Navigation Bar in App Delegate override the embedded navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 `view controllers` embedded in a `navigation bar controller`. Plus each view controller has a table view that covers the entire view.

The issue I am experiencing is that my `back button` (this is the left bar button item) in the `2nd view controller` **is not visible** though I can tap on the top left corner of the screen and it takes me back to the previous view controller. Thus, the button is present just not visible.

I do have this code in my App Delegate because I need to change the appearance of the header title of the Navigation Bar. Is this overriding my Nav Bar in some way?

-***AppDelegate.swift***

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        //change navigation bar appearance
        //--background color
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
        //--title color
        let fontColor = UIColor(red: 80/255.0, green: 80/255.0, blue: 80/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        let font = UIFont(name: "Verdana-Bold", size: 20)!
        let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [
            NSFontAttributeName: font,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: fontColor
        ]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributes

        return true
    }
```

I did verify in the `Attribute Inspector` in my `Navigation Controller Scene` that the property ***'Shows Navigation Bar'*** is `checked`.

I even tried to add a refresh button programmatically to the `1rst view controller` like so and I can see the print statement in the console meaning that when I press the top left corner the console prints ***"Refresh Button Pressed"*** but again the button is not visible even though it functions.

-***FirstViewController.swift***

```
// MARK: - Target Action functions
    @IBAction func refreshAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Refresh Button Pressed")
        //let _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

func setNavigationBarAttributes() {
        //set title for navigation bar (the appearance was changed in App Delegate)
        self.navigationItem.title = "NYC Schools"

        //refresh button
        let refreshButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        refreshButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "back_button.png"), for: .normal) // Image can be downloaded from here below link
        refreshButton.setTitle("Refresh", for: .normal)
        refreshButton.setTitleColor(refreshButton.tintColor, for: .normal) // You can change the TitleColor
        refreshButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refreshAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: refreshButton)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue with your invisible, working back button in your `2nd view controller` is the fact that you have set the navigation bar `barTintColor` to white, and also the `tintColor` to white. This gives you a white back button on a white navigation bar - making it invisible!

Try it again with these settings in your `AppDelegate`:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blue
```

As for your refresh button on the `1st view controller` - I think there's two possibilities for why you can't see it:

- "back_button.png" is a white or transparent image, which is not visible against the white navigation bar.
- the "back_button.png" image you specified does not exist and you're creating a button with no image at all, which (I think) would render it invisible.

Comment: I made these changes to the AppDelegate but still, the buttons are not visible.

Comment: The error was related to this, to the barTintColor and tintColor being the same. But it was additional code in my view controller that kept overriding it. Thanks for this find.